# Python Opencv Segmentation Fault VideoCapture

Tags: python, opencv

**Setup**:

```
Python 2.7.12
OpenCV: 3.4.0
Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
```

**Description**:

I've written a simple python program that reads a camera via a RTSP URL. The code of concern is as follows:

```
import cv2

url = "rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.1:554"

vcap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)

if (vcap.isOpened()):
    ret, image = vcap.read()
```

My code crashes at the line: `vcap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)`

I ran a backtrace using gdb and here's the output:

```
#0  0x00007fff9f3a9b70 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7
#1  0x00007fff9f3ab874 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7
#2  0x00007fff9f3ac175 in lt_dlopenadvise () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7
#3  0x00007fff9f3ac240 in lt_dlopenext () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7
#4  0x00007fffd3383b0e in gp_abilities_list_load_dir ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgphoto2.so.6
#5  0x00007fffd3383de9 in gp_abilities_list_load () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgphoto2.so.6
#6  0x00007fffd338645c in gp_camera_autodetect () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgphoto2.so.6
#7  0x00007fffee0c5765 in cv::gphoto2::DigitalCameraCapture::initContext() ()
   from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.4
#8  0x00007fffee0ccd89 in cv::gphoto2::DigitalCameraCapture::DigitalCameraCapture(cv::String const&)
    () from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.4
#9  0x00007fffee0cd2e6 in cv::createGPhoto2Capture(cv::String const&) ()
   from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.4
#10 0x00007fffee0a171f in cv::VideoCapture::open(cv::String const&, int) ()
   from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.4
#11 0x00007fffee0a26cb in cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(cv::String const&) ()
   from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.4
#12 0x00007ffff5864e27 in pyopencv_cv_VideoCapture_VideoCapture(pyopencv_VideoCapture_t*, _object*, _object*) () from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so
#13 0x00000000004aa9ab in type_call.lto_priv () at ../Objects/typeobject.c:765
#14 0x00000000004c15bf in PyObject_Call (kw=0x0, arg=(u'rtsp://admin:dsal12345@192.168.1.104:554',), 
    func=<type at remote 0x7ffff5e47200>) at ../Objects/abstract.c:2546
#15 do_call (nk=<optimized out>, na=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffef64524c0, 
    func=<type at remote 0x7ffff5e47200>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4567
#16 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffef64524c0) at ../Python/ceval.c:4372
#17 PyEval_EvalFrameEx () at ../Python/ceval.c:2987
#18 0x00000000004c136f in fast_function (nk=<optimized out>, na=<optimized out>, n=1, 
    pp_stack=0x7ffef64525e0, func=<function at remote 0x7fff89a6caa0>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4435
#19 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffef64525e0) at ../Python/ceval.c:4370
#20 PyEval_EvalFrameEx () at ../Python/ceval.c:2987
#21 0x00000000004b9ab6 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () at ../Python/ceval.c:3582
#22 0x00000000004d55f3 in function_call.lto_priv () at ../Objects/funcobject.c:523
#23 0x00000000004a577e in PyObject_Call () at ../Objects/abstract.c:2546
#24 0x00000000004bed3d in ext_do_call (nk=<optimized out>, na=<optimized out>, 
    flags=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffef6452868, func=<function at remote 0x7fff55a78c80>)
    at ../Python/ceval.c:4664
#25 PyEval_EvalFrameEx () at ../Python/ceval.c:3026
```

What are the potential solutions? Re-install opencv?

Any suggestions would be useful.

Comment: More radical, but try with some Python3? Try the same example in another library binding, like Java or C++?

Comment: Is that RTSP url correct? e.g. can you access the camera stream within VLC using that url?

Comment: Also you have a typo in your if statement - it should say "ret, image = vcap.read()"

Comment: Does it work when you have cv2.VideoCapture(0) ? because, if that runs that would mean opencv is working. I suspect you would have to decode the url. This [link](https://thecodacus.com/ip-webcam-opencv-wireless-camera/) might be useful.

Comment: @Wool thanks for the typo. Yes, the url is working. Even if it isn't, the method should not lead to a crash. It should just leave the vcap object unopened.